# Check if a given limit of a sequence is valid

Tags: calculus, limits

Using the definition of the limit with vicinities (rough translation from my native language) , prove that:
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {2^n+3}{2^n+4^n}=0 $$

For convenience I will take $a_n=\frac {2^n+3}{2^n+4^n}$

For this to be true I need to prove that inside any vicinity of the number 0 there are an infinity of terms from the sequence $(a_n)$.
In other words I need to prove that there exists a $n(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N^*}$ such that $0-\epsilon < a_n < 0+\epsilon \ \forall \ \epsilon>0,n>n(\epsilon) $.

The first thing I observed is that $a_n$ si strictly positive so it will always be greater than $-\epsilon$.
What remains to be proven is this:$a_n < \epsilon \ \forall \ \epsilon>0,n>n(\epsilon) $

Here is where I got stuck, how should I prove this?

NOTE: I use the word vicinity as a rough translation of a term in my native language, I am not sure that is the right term in English. I would be grateful if someone could clarify this as I am not able to find anything related to this on Google.

Comment: The term you're looking for in English is "neighborhood". `:)`

Comment: But I do like the word vicinity. Very well thought...

Comment: @user40615 Given that n is a positive integer, $ 3\leq4^n $ will always be true.

Comment: It is not sufficient " to prove that inside any vicinity of the number 0 there are an infinity of terms". You need to show that *almost all* terms are in the nighbourhood - or only finitely many are *not* in the neighbourhood.

Comment: You are right, so I deleted my comment

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Thanks for bringing this to light. Until now I thought that "all the terms except a finite number" was just a fancy way of saying an infinity

Comment: @classius Compare the truth of "Infinitely many natural numbers are odd" with "All but finitely many natural numbers are odd". In formalism, $\forall n\exists m>n\colon\ldots$ vs. $\exists n\forall m>n\colon \ldots$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Yep,just realized that :)

Comment: Thanks for the word "vicinity". It is much easier to type than "neighborhood" and at the same time it gives the essence of "nearness" which is the essential concept. Neighborhood seems to be more related to neighbors and not to nearness or distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for all $n\ge 2,$ we have $$\frac{2^n+3}{2^n+4^n}=\frac{2^n+3}{2^n(1+2^n)}\le\frac{2\cdot 2^n}{2^n(1+2^n)}\le\frac{2\cdot 2^n}{2^n\cdot 2^n}=\frac{2}{2^n}.$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: This would mean that I have to take $n(\epsilon)=[\log_2 \frac 2{\epsilon}$]+1. Right?(I used square brackets for the floor function)

Comment: That will do nicely, yes! Incidentally, you can use `$\lfloor$` and `$\rfloor$` for $\lfloor$ and $\rfloor$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge 0$ we have $3\le 3\cdot 2^n$, hence the numerator is $\le 4\cdot 2^n$. And the denominator is $>4^n$, hence $a_n<\frac{4\cdot 2^n}{4^n}=\frac4{2^n}$. For $\epsilon>0$ this is $<\epsilon$ if $\frac4\epsilon<2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$3\leq 2^n$ for $n\geq 1/2\ln 3=a$ and $2^n\leq 4^n$ for all $n$. Then $\frac{2^n+3}{2^n+4^n}\leq \frac{2.2^{n}}{2.4^n}\leq\frac{2^n}{2^{2n}}\leq \frac{1}{2^n}<\varepsilon$ when $n>-1/2\ln\varepsilon=b$. Set $N_0$ as the positive number of the  maximum of $a$ and $b$.